# Taking a poll of yes and no answers in a post

Tags: android

I'm kind of stumped in my search for this android library or api. (I'm a newbie in Android programming). 
I'm looking for help in how to display polled answers in my android app in terms of percentage or a kind of bar chart. 
I'd really appreciate any form of help. 
Anyone with ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.)